# Should we be helping with copyright infringement?

Tags: discussion, copyright

If you read the post:

[Recreating poster design from photograph](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144107/recreating-poster-design-from-photograph)

You will notice that the asker does indeed describe copyright infringement. While technically the question is good. I.e. how to de-skew images.

So:

- Should we edit the question not to include dubious description. (the question does not need it)
- Accept it in good faith.
- or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About answering**:

I agree with @Wolff.

We can never be sure if someone is the rightful owner of anything. We must assume that a question was asked in good faith unless it is a blatant 'how do I infringe on this copyright' question.

By all means, leave a comment under the question or in your answer if you think the OP might be infringing/is about to infringe on copyright. Warn them of possible consequences. That's where our responsibility ends. We teach techniques, that these techniques can be used for illegal activity doesn't mean it is wrong teaching them.

**About editing**:

You should edit those questions like any other in my opinion. If there is information that is not needed, and is distracting from the question itself, then by all means edit it out. If it's too insignificant, or an essential part of the question, leave it be.

If it is a question that needs to be flagged, flag it and don't edit. Editing out the offending parts makes it harder for us mods to later follow up on the flags and make a judgement. (much like [spam](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3727/psa-please-do-not-edit-spam))

Comment: No edit was necessary the op was willing to play ball and edit it down. NOTE: I wasnt so much concerned with OP breaking copyright but rather having a article that reads how do i copy posters. Which can give unnessesery ideas to people other than the OP

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one, but I lean towards just *answering the question in good faith* and add a comment warning about the possible copyright infringement.

First of all, recreating a copyrighted design for personal use isn't really illegal (or it doesn't matter if it is because no one will ever know). The legal problems arise if the copied design is *distributed*. Nothing wrong in copying some copyrighted design just for the sake of it, as long as the result is never shared with the world.

Secondly, recreating old designs is a part of the job of a graphic designer. A client could hire you to recreate some old logo, poster, drawing etc. If the client holds the copyright of the original, there is nothing wrong in recreating it. The involved disciplines could in my opinion be very suitable subjects for questions on this site.

In reality we can never really be sure if the OP is telling the truth. Any question about image editing could be met with an *"are you sure you are allowed to use that image?"* and the OP could simply answer *"yes"* and we would have to believe it.

In the given example we can't really know if the OP was actually hired by the person who holds the copyright of the posters. It isn't 100% clear that something illegal is going on, so I would give them the benefit of the doubt, but of course mention the copyright issue.

We've had other questions where it's much more obvious that answering the question would actually help the OP break the law. Questions like *"How do I make t-shirts with Disney characters?"*, *"How do I bypass this copy protection?"* and similar, which clearly don't even come from the desire to learn a technique, but more from a desire to make quick money stealing, shouldn't be encouraged.

Comment: You dont seem to tackle the should we edit it down... Also Logos are a bit more straight forward.